# Getting rid of bullet point and indentation in itemize

Tags: formatting, indentation, itemize

I'm writing my resume in LaTeX and am using `itemize` to list my employment history. Example:

```
\begin{itemize*}

\item
\headerrow{\textbf{Google}}{\textbf{Cambridge, MA}}
\headerrow{\emph{Software Engineering Intern}}{\emph{Summer 2015}}
\begin{itemize*}
\item Blah blah blah
\item Blah blah blah
\end{itemize*}

\end{itemize*}
```

is one entry (obviously without the blah blah blah). Note that `headerrow` is a custom environment that I've created with the following definition:

```
\newcommand{\headerrow}[2]
{\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    #1 &
    #2 \\
\end{tabular*}}
```

This produces the following result:

[image]

How could I get rid of the bullet point (and associated indentation) with the item "Google"? I've looked around and seen a few people asking how to get rid of just the bullet point, but I would also like to get rid of the indentation, so that the word "Google" is flush (or nearly flush) with the word "Experience".

Any way to do this?

Comment: Please edit your question so that it contains a complete example document that reproduces the problem. This will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: You might try the description environment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you want to use `itemize`; however, here's a possibility.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newenvironment{outeritemize}
 {\begin{itemize}[label={},leftmargin=*]}
 {\end{itemize}}

\newcommand{\headerrow}[2]{%
  \hspace*{-\labelsep}%
  \begin{tabular*}{\dimexpr\linewidth+\labelsep}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lr@{}}
    #1 &
    #2 \\
  \end{tabular*}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2] % to show the margins

\section*{Experience}

\begin{outeritemize}

\item
\headerrow{\textbf{Google}}{\textbf{Cambridge, MA}}
\headerrow{\emph{Software Engineering Intern}}{\emph{Summer 2015}}
\begin{itemize}
\item Blah blah blah
\item Blah blah blah
\end{itemize}

\end{outeritemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `trivlist` environment which does not insert bullets or indents:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newcommand{\headerrow}[2]{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lr@{}}
    #1 &
    #2 \\
  \end{tabular*}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2] % to show the margins

\section*{Experience}

\begin{trivlist}

\item
\headerrow{\textbf{Google}}{\textbf{Cambridge, MA}}
\headerrow{\emph{Software Engineering Intern}}{\emph{Summer 2015}}
\begin{itemize}
\item Blah blah blah
\item Blah blah blah
\end{itemize}

\end{trivlist}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you provide empty `\item[]`, then the bullet will not appear within the list.

With regard to the indentation, if you just want to avoid it in the mentioned area, then one of the solution is to adjust the left skip:

```
\begin{itemize*}
\leftskip-\dimexpr\leftmargin %%% 
\item[]
\headerrow{\textbf{Google}}{\textbf{Cambridge, MA}}\\ %%% Ensure linebreak
\headerrow{\emph{Software Engineering Intern}}{\emph{Summer 2015}}
```

Comment: This makes the spacing look awkward on the right hand side. The location and dates end up too far to the left.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  A slight amendment in `\headerrow` command will do the trick.

   `\newcommand{\headerrow}[2]
    {\begin{tabular*}{\dimexpr\leftmargin+\linewidth}    {@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
        #1 &
        #2 \\
    \end{tabular*}}`